# Eureka server can't detect AWS

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to run a Eureka server in AWS.

I created a Springboot app annotated with @EnableEurekaServer but whenever the app started in AWS i got the following log message:

```
2017-03-29 04:11:39.886  INFO 19046 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : isAws returned false
```

Worried that I had done something wrong in my app I tried out the Eureka Spring cloud sample from https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/eureka.git

I have the exact same problem - even though I am running on an EC2 instance, Eureka fails to detect this.

The server itself does start but it is ignoring all of my AWS specific config such as EIP binding.

Here is the full log output from running `mvn clean spring-boot:run`

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ eureka ---
2017-03-29 04:17:16.178  INFO 19466 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1a19b36d: startup date [Wed Mar 29 04:17:16 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-29 04:17:16.575  INFO 19466 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-03-29 04:17:16.607  INFO 19466 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d153893] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.3.RELEASE)

2017-03-29 04:17:16.927  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
2017-03-29 04:17:17.006  WARN 19466 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/eureka/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-03-29 04:17:17.007  INFO 19466 --- [           main] eurekademo.EurekaApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-03-29 04:17:17.020  INFO 19466 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5a6e74a7: startup date [Wed Mar 29 04:17:17 UTC 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1a19b36d
2017-03-29 04:17:17.715  WARN 19466 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2017-03-29 04:17:17.852  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=512ba4fc-847f-3775-a8eb-3c9786c9462f
2017-03-29 04:17:17.899  INFO 19466 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-03-29 04:17:17.931  INFO 19466 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d153893] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-29 04:17:18.149  INFO 19466 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
2017-03-29 04:17:18.159  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-03-29 04:17:18.160  INFO 19466 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2017-03-29 04:17:18.246  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-03-29 04:17:18.247  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1227 ms
2017-03-29 04:17:18.608  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-29 04:17:18.608  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-29 04:17:18.608  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-29 04:17:18.608  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-29 04:17:18.609  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-29 04:17:18.609  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-29 04:17:18.609  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'servletContainer' to urls: [/eureka/*]
2017-03-29 04:17:18.609  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-29 04:17:18.609  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-03-29 04:17:18.677  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl           : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
2017-03-29 04:17:18.732  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-03-29 04:17:18.733  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-03-29 04:17:18.819  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2017-03-29 04:17:18.820  INFO 19466 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2017-03-29 04:17:19.119  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2017-03-29 04:17:19.159  INFO 19466 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2017-03-29 04:17:19.167  INFO 19466 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1490761039167 with initial instances count: 0
2017-03-29 04:17:19.231  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initializing ...
2017-03-29 04:17:19.233  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Adding new peer nodes [http://localhost:8761/eureka/]
2017-03-29 04:17:19.339  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-03-29 04:17:19.339  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2017-03-29 04:17:19.339  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2017-03-29 04:17:19.339  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2017-03-29 04:17:19.432  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Replica node URL:  http://localhost:8761/eureka/
2017-03-29 04:17:19.440  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Finished initializing remote region registries. All known remote regions: []
2017-03-29 04:17:19.440  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initialized
2017-03-29 04:17:20.003  INFO 19466 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5a6e74a7: startup date [Wed Mar 29 04:17:17 UTC 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1a19b36d
2017-03-29 04:17:20.093  INFO 19466 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/lastn],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaController.lastn(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2017-03-29 04:17:20.094  INFO 19466 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaController.status(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2017-03-29 04:17:20.096  INFO 19466 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-03-29 04:17:20.096  INFO 19466 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-03-29 04:17:20.125  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-29 04:17:20.125  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-29 04:17:20.158  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-29 04:17:20.562  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.value(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2017-03-29 04:17:20.562  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/reset],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.reset()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.564  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.565  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
2017-03-29 04:17:20.565  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.566  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
2017-03-29 04:17:20.566  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/resume || /resume.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.566  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/pause || /pause.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.567  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.568  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/refresh || /refresh.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.569  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2017-03-29 04:17:20.569  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.571  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2017-03-29 04:17:20.571  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.572  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/features || /features.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.574  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.575  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/archaius || /archaius.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.575  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.575  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/restart || /restart.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.576  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.576  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-03-29 04:17:20.669  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : SpringTemplateLoader for FreeMarker: using resource loader [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5a6e74a7: startup date [Wed Mar 29 04:17:17 UTC 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1a19b36d] and template loader path [classpath:/templates/]
2017-03-29 04:17:20.670  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.v.f.FreeMarkerConfigurer         : ClassTemplateLoader for Spring macros added to FreeMarker configuration
2017-03-29 04:17:20.744  WARN 19466 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2017-03-29 04:17:20.744  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2017-03-29 04:17:20.749  WARN 19466 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2017-03-29 04:17:20.749  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2017-03-29 04:17:20.816  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-03-29 04:17:20.823  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-03-29 04:17:20.824  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-03-29 04:17:20.826  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-03-29 04:17:20.826  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-03-29 04:17:20.827  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'restartEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-03-29 04:17:20.829  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2017-03-29 04:17:20.840  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'restartEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.restart:name=restartEndpoint,type=RestartEndpoint]
2017-03-29 04:17:20.849  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2017-03-29 04:17:20.856  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=5a6e74a7,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2017-03-29 04:17:20.861  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.endpoint:name=refreshEndpoint,type=RefreshEndpoint]
2017-03-29 04:17:21.053  INFO 19466 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2017-03-29 04:17:21.067  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Registering application eureka with eureka with status UP
2017-03-29 04:17:21.070  INFO 19466 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Setting the eureka configuration..
2017-03-29 04:17:21.070  INFO 19466 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Eureka data center value eureka.datacenter is not set, defaulting to default
2017-03-29 04:17:21.070  INFO 19466 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Eureka environment value eureka.environment is not set, defaulting to test
2017-03-29 04:17:21.097  INFO 19466 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : isAws returned false
2017-03-29 04:17:21.098  INFO 19466 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Initialized server context
2017-03-29 04:17:21.098  INFO 19466 --- [      Thread-10] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Got 1 instances from neighboring DS node
2017-03-29 04:17:21.098  INFO 19466 --- [      Thread-10] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Renew threshold is: 1
2017-03-29 04:17:21.098  INFO 19466 --- [      Thread-10] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Changing status to UP
2017-03-29 04:17:21.105  INFO 19466 --- [      Thread-10] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server
2017-03-29 04:17:21.154  INFO 19466 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http)
2017-03-29 04:17:21.155  INFO 19466 --- [           main] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Updating port to 8761
2017-03-29 04:17:21.158  INFO 19466 --- [           main] eurekademo.EurekaApplication             : Started EurekaApplication in 5.439 seconds (JVM running for 8.49)
2017-03-29 04:17:26.523  INFO 19466 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-03-29 04:17:26.523  INFO 19466 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-03-29 04:17:26.534  INFO 19466 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 11 ms
```

I think if isAws was equal to true then my problems would be solved but there is no other detail with that message as to why Eureka thinks it isn't running in AWS even though it is.

I have also tried passing the parameter -Deureka.datacenter=cloud to no effect.

To test this out just spin up any ec2 instance (a t2.medium in my case), install git and maven (java8 should already be installed), checkout https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/eureka.git, run the sprintboot app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out.

Out of the box, Springboot Eureka doesn't include the required dependency to work out if it's in AWS or not.

I added the following to the POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Once I had done that then Eureka was able to determine it was in AWS.

Note that I think you can play with this dependency - I think all that is required is the AWS ec2 dependency `com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ec2` but I never tested this.